# While Loop not working

Tags: python, while-loop

A while back I was tasked to design a currency converter as part of my school project. I remember including a 'while loop' which worked perfectly. However, when I looked back over the program again and tested it, the while loop no longer worked.

I'm hoping someone could explain why the while loop isn't working. Maybe it never worked and I'm just remembering incorrectly, or maybe something changed within the code which has caused it to not work?

```
while True:  #first while loop - repeats entire program unless broken 
while True: #second while loop - repeats input section of code unless broken
    currentcurrency = input ("Select a starting currency: ") #allows user to input their starting currency, saved as a string in variable 'currentcurrency'
    print ('You selected %s' % currentcurrency) #prints inputted string

    value = float(input ("Input your current value: ")) #allows user to input their value of money, saved as a float in variable 'value'

    newcurrency =  input ("Select a new currency: ")  #allows the user to input their new currency, saved as a string in variable 'newcurrency' 
    if currentcurrency == 'Pound' and newcurrency == 'Pound': #this part of the code determines the convertor value based upon the two inputted currencies
        convertor = 1
    if currentcurrency == 'Pound' and newcurrency == 'Euro':
        convertor = 1.34
    if currentcurrency == 'Pound' and newcurrency == 'Dollar':
        convertor = 1.46
    if currentcurrency == 'Pound' and newcurrency == 'Yen':

        convertor = 171.61
    if currentcurrency == 'Euro' and newcurrency == 'Pound':
        convertor = 0.75

    if currentcurrency == 'Euro' and newcurrency == 'Euro':
        convertor = 1
    if currentcurrency == 'Euro' and newcurrency == 'Dollar':
        convertor = 1.09
    if currentcurrency == 'Euro' and newcurrency == 'Yen':
        convertor = 127.47
    if currentcurrency == 'Dollar' and newcurrency == 'Pound':
        convertor = 0.69
    if currentcurrency == 'Dollar' and newcurrency == 'Euro':
        convertor = 0.88
    if currentcurrency == 'Dollar' and newcurrency == 'Dollar':
        convertor = 1
    if currentcurrency == 'Dollar' and newcurrency == 'Yen':
        convertor = 121.12
    if currentcurrency == 'Yen' and newcurrency == 'Pound':
        convertor = 0.0062
    if currentcurrency == 'Yen' and newcurrency == 'Euro':
        convertor = 0.0076
    if currentcurrency == 'Yen' and newcurrency == 'Dollar':
        convertor = 0.0083
    if currentcurrency == 'Yen' and newcurrency == 'Yen':
        convertor = 1

    print ("Do you want to convert", (value), (currentcurrency), "to", (newcurrency), "?")
    answer = input ("Yes/No: ")  #allows the user to input a response, saved in variable 'answer'
    if answer == 'Yes' or 'y' or 'yes': #if the user inputted string is 'Yes' or equivelant,
        break                           #the while loop will break, and the program will continue

result = (convertor) * (value)          #calculates the result by multiplying the user inputted value and the converter
result *= 100                           #this part of the code calculates the result to two decimal places
result += 0.5                           #it multiplies the result by 100 and adds 0.5
result = int(result)                    #then changes the result to an integer
result /= float(100)                    #divides the result by a 100 and changes it to a float
print (result, newcurrency)             #prints the result, followed by the new currency

answer2 = input("Do you want to convert again? (Yes/No): ") #allows the user to input an answer
if answer2 == 'No' or 'n' or 'no': #if the inputted answer is 'No' or equivalent,
    break                          #the while loop breaks and the code continues - otherwise, it repeasts the program
exit()                                 #ends the program
```

Thanks, please explain simply because I'm not very experienced with the program!

EDIT: Formatting error. Real code looks like this: 
[Currency Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXRQn.png)

Comment: The first loop has no body, so it never breaks out of the loop. Did you mean to indent the second loop so it's inside the first one?

Comment: you need one more indentation since 2nd line

Comment: Why don't you edit your code instead of linking an image?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 nested loops here, so the second one needs two be indented :

```
while True:  
    while True: #requires indentation
        currentcurrency = input ("Select a starting currency: ")
        [...]
```

Comment: Didn't notice this, but I made a formatting error when writing the code to this website. The real code does have an indent on the second loop - I've inserted an image of it to the original post. 
Thanks for the reply nonetheless.

Comment: Which error do you get when you launch this script ?